# Symbian simulate keyboard input

Tags: c++, qt, keyboard, symbian, textinput

I have created a Qt background task that generates text on account of user input. My task runs when a text input field is open, what I now need is a way to insert text into the input of whatever application is currently open. I have looked at key press simulation but I cannot find a method that works.

Do you gave any idea what I can do?

PS. This is for Symbian^3(Belle) and Qt as well as Symbian C++ code will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On way to do it is

```
            RWsSession sess=CCoeEnv::Static()->WsSession();
        sess.SimulateKeyEvent(RFB::GetKeyEvent(code,ETrue));
        User::After(200000); 
        sess.Flush();
```